# Python Flask serve .htm files, possible?

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm a Python beginner. I have hundreds of static .htm files (NOT .html) that I want to display.

What's the best way for me to do this?

Thanks so much

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template, request, session, flash, Response, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'hello'

@app.route('/view')
def view():
    return render_template("example.htm")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: htm is the same as html, just the extension is different.

Comment: @spg719 The expectation of your question is a bit vague. What are you expecting for an answer? Is htm possible to be shown via flask app or the best possible way to serve the htm pages?

Comment: @NagarajTantri My question is how to do both. sorry for being vague

Comment: Just server the static files via your web server, e.g. nginx.

Comment: @spg719 No need to be apologetic. Can you update your question a bit? Add things like:  `You are looking for both best possible way to serve htm pages`, `Ensuring to use Python Flask to serve all the htm pages`. Are you open for suggestions which are not Python-Flask only? Are you have only static files here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have hundreds of static .htm files, I imagine writing a Flask View file manually would be very, very tedious. :-(

Fortunately, you can use Python to read a list of your files and write more Python code and a View.py file for you! :-)

Put the following code in a file (say) "view_builder.py" in the same folder as your HTM files, then execute it from a cmd prompt in that folder : (python3 view_builder.py)

```
import glob
  
# start a file for the Flask Views    
view_file = open("view.py", "a")

# first write the View file header with Flask imports

fileline = "from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template, request, session, flash, Response, jsonify" + "\n\n"
view_file.write(fileline)
fileline = "app = Flask(__name__)" + "\n"
view_file.write(fileline)
fileline = "app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'hello'" + "\n"+ "\n"
view_file.write(fileline)

# assuming all views will have the same name as original HTM file

# filetype may be case sensitive?
for file in glob.glob("*.HTM"):
    # split file into filename and filetype
    fileparts = file.split('.')
    # build the app route and view def() with just the filename (no need for filetype)
    fileline = "@app.route('/" + fileparts[0] + "')" + "\n"
    view_file.write(fileline)
    fileline = "def " + fileparts[0] + "():" + "\n"
    view_file.write(fileline)
    # use the whole file name (with filetype) for the template file 
    fileline = "    return render_template('" + file + "')" + "\n"+ "\n"
    view_file.write(fileline)
    
# View.py file footer

fileline = 'if __name__ == "__main__":' + "\n"
view_file.write(fileline)
fileline = '    app.run(debug=True)' + "\n"
view_file.write(fileline)
view_file.close
```